# Why I can't read property during the test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have some controls on the page:

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" autocomplete="off" *ngIf="displayRegistration">
    <mat-card id="registrationCard">
        <mat-card-title>Create new account for your email address</mat-card-title>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Nick name</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" id="playerNick" formControlName="playerNick" [value]="playerNick" [(ngModel)]="playerNick">
            <mat-hint align="end">4-15 alphanumeric characters long</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button id="registerButton" (click)="register()" [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid">Register</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</form>
<div>Nick: {{playerNick}}</div>
```

During my tests I put data into:

```
function createComponentAndDetectChanges() {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
}

fit(
  'when user clicks populates forms, data should be filled properly',
  waitForAsync(async () => {
    createComponentAndDetectChanges();
    component.displayRegistrationDiv = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    enterNickAndClickRegister(false);

    const btn = getRegisterButtonHarness();
    (await btn).focus();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    console.log(component.registrationForm.value);
    console.log(component.registrationForm.get('playerNick').value);
    console.log(component.playerNick);
    expect(component.playerNick).toBe(playerNickForTest);
  })
);

async function enterNickAndClickRegister(click: boolean) {
  const registerButton = await getRegisterButtonHarness();
  expect(registerButton).toBeTruthy();
  expect(await registerButton.isDisabled()).toBeTrue();

  const playerNickInput: MatInputHarness = await getPlayerNickInputHarness();
  expect(playerNickInput).toBeTruthy();
  await playerNickInput.setValue(playerNickForTest);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(await registerButton.isDisabled()).toBeFalse();

  if (click) await registerButton.click();
}

async function getRegisterButtonHarness(): Promise<MatButtonHarness> {
  return await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness.with({ text: 'Register' }));
}

async function getPlayerNickInputHarness(): Promise<MatInputHarness> {
  return await loader.getHarness(MatInputHarness.with({ selector: '#playerNick' }));
}
```

Things work properly during the run-time, also the 'playerNick' property of the component is populated properly as Karma properly displays its value:
[image]

But somehow, all 3 lines I put into the console display empty lines.

Why and how to fix that?

Comment: for `console.log(component.registrationForm.value)` are you getting null string or the initial value of form as object?

Comment: I do get the object, but its value is null. Here is what's in the console:: {playerNick: null}